# How do I remove index.php from url in CodeIgniter 2.2

Tags: mod-rewrite, codeigniter

I have tried all the methods I can find on the web but nothing seems to work. I still get a 404 page. I already modified $config['index_page'] = ''; and add the lines to .htaccess as suggested by the ci documentation site. Please help. I am stressed with this for a whole day now!

these are what I put in .htaccess. I am using LAMP

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code with .htaccess file.

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`